# Speech to text in multiple languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, speech-to-text

i have success fully implemented the ispeech API see http://www.ispeech.org/developers for my app to convert speech to text(see the demo app in the sdk http://www.ispeech.org/instructions/sampleprojects/iphone/IntegrationGuide.html). But unfortunately it takes what we speak as only in english and translte it to text.

what i need.

There is a "speak" button that listens what the user spokes and convert it to text(that works fine for english). Also another button that allows the user to select a language as seen in this appscreenshot( http://screencast.com/t/7vBFH565qD). So when the user speaks in the selected language it should get converted to the same language. In my case whatever we speak it takes the input only in english..

Thanks all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you use the NUANCE API which supports speech to text in multiple languages. see the following link and register there to use their iOS sdk .

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=supportedLanguages

Comment: is that free or not and need to use internet connection?

Comment: need internet connection. but free

Answer (score 3):

iSpeech also supports more languages, you can find the list with their corresponding locale identifiers here:
http://www.ispeech.org/api

To set a new language you have the "ISpeechSetLocale" method

[_iSpeech ISpeechSetLocale:@"fr-FR"];

http://www.ispeech.org/developer/iframe?src=/iphonesdkdoc/